Kosh and Talia's memories
In the B-plot of the episode Deathwalker, Ambassador Kosh 'hires' Talia Winters to telepathically monitor some negotiations with Abbut, a seemingly eccentric human. However not only do the so-called negotiations amount to nonsensical phrases batted back and forth, but during the sessions Talia finds herself reliving traumatic memories from her past, including when she once probed the mind of a serial killer. Eventually Abbut reveals himself to be a kind of cyborg who somehow 'records' these memories on a data crystal he gives to Kosh.
I have yet to have seen a follow-up to these events either in the show or any of the Babylon 5 movies- was something planned but couldn't be executed for some reason?

Ultimately Talia in the big picture was Lyta's replacement.  When Talia left Lyta took her story back.  If Talia stayed and Lyta never came back we can safely assume Kosh would have had a super powered telepathic assistant that would later be sympathetic to the telepath underground railroad and Byron's group.  Note Talia got the power boost from Ironheart.  Lyta from an offscreen visit to the Vorlon homeworld.

Whatever was planned, the 'some reason' it could not be executed was Talia's actress,
Andrea Thompson, wanted to leave the show for other work.  JMS was always prepared for actors/actresses leaving and there was an extra convenient way here, letting the sleeper take over without fixing it (and killing her off, if Bester is to be believed).

At one point JMS was reputed to have said "Talia's brain is in a jar on Bester's desk."  Minor case of burned bridges there...

"Whatever was planned, the 'some reason' it could not be executed was Talia's actress, Andrea Thompson, wanted to leave the show" - I'm not sure where I read this now, but I came across some statement indicating the entire point of the data crystal was to bring Talia back/"reset" her from the sleeper agent personality, should the actress return.

Also, JMS did not like it.  Quote from the Season 1 guide.  "That one was a Larry [DiTillo] construct that I really wasn't that happy with," he says.  "I didn't care for the Vicker.  I wasn't sure I wanted that technolgy in my universe and after it was put in, I thought 'I'm never going to see this ever again' - they all died!"
